# Need to store No.of data from Editorfor field in View to a List in Controller (C#.NET MVC-4)

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, razor

I am developing a webpage to display BOM details. So, I have added `EditorFor` field in View with `Add` button. Once I enter the data in Field and click `Add`, It will display the data to a table. Likewise, I will enter number of data in `EditorFor` field and It displays all the data in the Table as I expected.
But the thing is, I need all the data which I was entered in the `EditorFor` field should moves to the controller need to carry all the data in a List.

**View:**

```html
@model Admin.Models.BOMFields
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "BOM_Add_Data";
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("Product_details", "BOM", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <table class="table" style="border-top:none;">
        <tr style="width: 250px;">
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Part_No)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Part_No, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "part_no" } })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "description" } })
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Quantity)
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Quantity, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @id = "quantity" } })
            </td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-default" id="add_btn" type="button" onclick="addField(this);" style="margin-top:25%;">Add</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table class="table" id="tbl" style="border:none;margin-top:2%;">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Part_No)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Description)
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Quantity)
            </th>
        </tr>
    </table>
    
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-offset-8 col-md-10" style="margin-top:2%;">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-default" />
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
}
<script>
    function addField(argument) {
        var myTable = document.getElementById("tbl");
        var currentIndex = myTable.rows.length;
        var currentRow = myTable.insertRow(-1);

        var Part_No_Box = document.createElement("td");
        Part_No_Box.setAttribute("name", "Part_No" + currentIndex);

        var Descp_Box = document.createElement("td");
        Descp_Box.setAttribute("name", "Description" + currentIndex);

        var Quan_Box = document.createElement("td");
        Quan_Box.setAttribute("name", "Quantity" + currentIndex);

        var currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(Part_No_Box);
        currentCell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("part_no").value;
        currentCell.style.border = "1px solid black";

        currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(Descp_Box);
        currentCell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("description").value;
        currentCell.style.border = "1px solid black";

        currentCell = currentRow.insertCell(-1);
        currentCell.appendChild(Quan_Box);
        currentCell.innerHTML = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
        currentCell.style.border = "1px solid black";
    }
</script>
```

**Model:**

```js
public class BOMFields
    {
        [DisplayName("Part-No")]
        [Required]
        public string Part_No { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Description")]
        [Required]
        public string Description { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Quantity")]
        [Required]
        public string Quantity { get; set; }
        public string Part_No_List { get; set; }
        public string Description_List { get; set; }
        public string Quantity_List { get; set; }
    }
```

**BOM Insert:**

```js
public class BOM_Insert
    {
        public List<BOMFields> Table(string cPart_No, string cDescription, string cQuantity)
        {
            List<BOMFields> ItemQm = new List<BOMFields>();
            ItemQm.Add(new BOMFields {Part_No_List = cPart_No,Description_List = cDescription,Quantity_List = cQuantity});
            return (ItemQm);
        }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```js
public class BOMController : Controller
    {
        // GET: BOM
        public ActionResult BOM_Add_Data()
        {
            return View();

        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Product_details(BOMFields new_data)
        {
            BOM_Insert dblogin = new BOM_Insert();
            var Part_Nos = dblogin.Table(new_data.Part_No, new_data.Description, new_data.Quantity);
            BOM_Add_Data();
            return View("BOM_Add_Data");
        }
    }
```

Once I'll add all my data to table It will display like this
[click here to see the View image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aaYLm.png)

After click `submit`, the page redirects to controller to send the data from `EditorFor` to `Product_details()`. But I'll get only the last data which I was entered in `EditorFor`[click here to see the Data viewed in the list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5p2DF.png).

How can I get all the the data which I was entered in `EditorFor` from view and store as a single list in controller. Because, I need to share all the data to the Database once I click the `submit` button.